# Pose only saving some bone transformations in pose library

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I am trying to add new poses into my pose library for a butterfly rig. The rig operates as expected, and all the bones can be key-framed for animation. However, when I try and save a pose into the pose library, it is only saving the transformations on some bones. Specifically, it is not saving the location, rotation, or scale on any of the wing bones or the main root bone, only the location of the IK handles for the legs.

Is there any sort of common cause for such an issue and does anyone have any experience fixing it? I have encountered it in other scene files, and often brute force/saving/reloading/selecting everything when adding pose would often accidentally fix it to a usable degree (eventually), but in this instance, nothing is working.

Comment: The pose is only saved for selected bones. Did you select everything before saving?